# Lost files in iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, storage, nsfilemanager

I have a app that downloads video and image files from a server. I store these files in folders in my app. I have 3 different places where i store the files:

1. Caches Directory - Videos + Images downloaded
2. Application Support Directory - Database
3. Documents Directory - Videos taken by current user

The code that i use to get paths to these folders is:

```
+ (NSString *)FilesStoreDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

    NSString *path = paths.count ? [(NSURL *)paths.firstObject path] : NSTemporaryDirectory();

    NSString *result = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"files"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:result])
    {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:result withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }

    return result;
}
```

At the logout i remove all these folders and files. The database (sql) is the only file that is not deleted.

My problem is that the size of the app increases while use. I have a example of 4 GB of stored files and after logout it went down to 1.9 GB when it should only be 23 MB + database (small). The way that a check how big is the app is by checking Settings -> Usage.

I am thinking maybe there is a problem with the folder creation and it creates different folders between different runs of the app, but that didn't solve the problem.

I play these video files so i suspect the AVPlayer of caching these files and not letting them go. But that is just a hunch.

Anybody has a idea why this is happening, and how can i get back to 23 MB of app size?

Thanks.

LATER EDIT:

This is the code that i use to remove the folders:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[LVCoreDataController FilesStoreDirectory] error:nil];
```

Comment: What size you get when you freshly install your app? Your app might be using image caching or, other libraries, which stores files in different folder, those might not be deleted?

Comment: Please share the code which you used to remove the folders. Also please check the home directory size after logout.

Comment: I have a 23 MB app size after fresh install. I removed any cache done by NSURLSession. I have a Core Data SQL Database for persistance, and every file that i download it's saved in the folders above.

Comment: @abyt07 i added the line of code that i use to remove the folders

Comment: It seems like you are removing only Cache/Temp Directory. You are not removing NSDocumentDirectory where you are saving Videos taken by current user.

Comment: @abyt07 I have the lines of code that removes the other two folders, i just didn't wrote them because they are all alike. Sorry for the missing info.

Comment: You can use Xcode to examine the app's sandbox or export it to your computer to see what it contains after your deletion.